# In MapBasic, how do I allow a user to choose a folder?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I have used the FileOpenDlg() function to allow the user to choose a file.  I would like to do the same thing to allow them to choose a folder so I can save files to the folder without the user having to interact every time a file saves.  Is there a function for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no MapBasic command to get a directory path. You can extract the directory from a full file path string and truncating at the last \ etc, but it's messy and not a nice solution.

A much better way is to use a Shell API or .NET function, some examples of which can be found here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mapinfo-l/MGFhmQSpmwo/7irVqnPhZosJ